# Save the result from "summary(lm)" to use in PowerBi

Tags: r, ggplot2, lm

Is it possible to save an summary(lm) object in a format usable in PowerBI?

Lets say the following:

```
data <- mpg
lm <- lm(hwy ~ displ, data = mpg)
summary(lm)
```

Output:

```
Call:
lm(formula = hwy ~ displ, data = mpg)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-7.1039 -2.1646 -0.2242  2.0589 15.0105 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  35.6977     0.7204   49.55   <2e-16 ***
displ        -3.5306     0.1945  -18.15   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 3.836 on 232 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.5868,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.585 
F-statistic: 329.5 on 1 and 232 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

I would lake to save this information as gglpot2 object, or picture in general, that I can display in Power BI. So that we can use this as a template for a fast regressions inside Power BI. This since Power BI only can display R code that results in a "plot" and not text.

I have tried:

```
textplot(capture.output(summary(lm)))
```

But I first got this error:

```
>install.packages('textplot')
Warning in install.packages : 
    package ‘textplot’ is not available (for R version 3.5.3)
```

And unfortunately Power BI doesn't supports textplot().

EDIT: Clarification I'm not looking to plot a regression line nor plane. I'm looking for a way to save the text output from "summary(lm)" as a plot object that I can display in Power BI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
fit <- lm(hwy ~ displ, data = mpg)
txt = capture.output(print(summary(fit)))

plot(NULL,xlim=c(-1,1),ylim=c(-1,1),xaxt="n",yaxt="n",bty="n",xlab="",ylab="")
text(x=0,y=0,paste(txt,collapse="\n"))
```

[image]

You might need to look at using stringr::str_pad to make the text prettier.. but this should get you something that works.

This is how you put it on ggplot2:

```
ggplot() + xlim(c(-1,1)) + ylim(c(-1,1)) + 
geom_text(aes(x=0,y=0,label=paste(txt,collapse="\n"))) + 
    theme_void()
```

[image]

Comment: Very cool. You may left align with `hjust = 0` if you prefer.

Comment: you're welcome.. quite an interesting problem actually :)

Answer (score 0):

[This example](https://sejohnston.com/2012/08/09/a-quick-and-easy-function-to-plot-lm-results-in-r/) should be useful for you.  To apply here:

```
plot(hwy ~ displ, data=mpg)
abline(lm1)
```

[image]

For the `ggplot2` solution, this works:

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method='lm', formula=y~x)
```

[image]

Comment: No, it wouldn't. Since I would like to add more than 1 predictor. I want the summary table with all the estimates, std, etc.